# How to print out your list in alphabetical order without changing the order of items in the list

Tags: python, list

How to print out your list in alphabetical order without changing the order of items in the list.

Comment: Can this be achieved without using loop or if statement

Comment: `print(sorted(my_list))`?

Comment: You need to sort the list and then iterate over the result to print each item.  There are number of ways that you might do this, but they all involve creating either a new list that is sorted or a generator that returns items in sorted order.  Using Python's `sorted` function is the most straightforward way to do this.